# How to find optimal number of threads to calculate a really large vector's sum using modern c++?

Tags: c++, c++17

How to find optimal number of threads to calculate a really large vector's sum using modern c++?
I know similar questions/answers are available. But say I don't know what configuration of prod machine will be . Still the approach should take least time

Comment: Use the OS API to find out the number of available cores. The number of threads can be 1-2 times as many as there are cores, depending on other factors that can only be figured out when you try it.

Comment: the same number of threads as the maximum hyper-tread cores your machine could possibly have.

Comment: [`std::thread::hardware_concurrency`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency)

Comment: @Evg: How is that specified to handle hardware features like [HyperThreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading)? It's not obvious.

Comment: @einpoklum I guess it's not. On my machine is return the number of logical cores.

Comment: @Evg: So there's that. Also, maybe you want to account on the load on your system due to other work. Or not.

Comment: @einpoklum Sure. That link was mostly to support the first comment - "to find out the number of available cores".

Comment: I've used `hardware_concurrency` to make my own thread pools but sometimes they just take too much out of the system. Balancing "on the go" is hard. Using the execution policies is usually nicer to the system _and_ being really fast (if the data is properly organized).

Comment: You should also consider using vectorization (SIMD) and enable avx512 in your compiler settings. Assuming you compile to a platform that supports that. 
Here is an overview : http://0x80.pl/notesen/2019-02-02-autovectorization-gcc-clang.html

Answer (score 5):

You don't, that's the implementations job. You call `std::reduce` with `std::execution::parallel_unsequenced_policy`.

(C++11 `std::accumulate` is specified too tightly to be executed in parallel.)

Comment: I would add a concrete code snippet just to round this out.

Comment: `auto res = std::reduce(std::execution::par_unseq, foo.begin(), foo.end(), 0);`